# Win 7 vs MWHS 2011

Tags: windows-7, home-server

I currently have a computer that basically all it does is stores movies, music, and backs up data that I want it too. It is also connected to the family TV to watch the movies that are stored on that computer.

The question is whether I should use Win 7 or MWHS 2011 for the OS.

OR

I also have an old Lenovo Thinkcentre that I stopped using because it gets hot. 80C while idle. should I revive that box and store the movies and stuff on there and just stream that to the computer that is connected to the TV.

Trying to find the most efficient/practical layout for this and whether I should use Windows 7 or Microsoft Windows Home Server 2011.

Comment: I just upgraded from WHS2003 to WHS2011. I like the change. I currently have WHS2011 running on 2 Core Xeon E3-1270, 2GB Ram, 512GB HDD in a virtual environment. It does a great job and streaming on it is flawless. I have a Core i3 2100 for my media center and it streams from the WHS2011 virtual machine.

Comment: but should i have WHS on the computer that plays movies on the TV or should that have Win 7 and have WHS on a seperate computer?

Comment: Personally, I would have WHS on another computer simply because I like doing the backups on the media center computer. If that computer dies, I can restore to a previous backup from the WHS. I may be an exception to the case though since I use a Ceton Tuner. If you do a new install, any protected content would have to be deleted. This way, I won't lose my 174 recorded shows.